# AutoHotKey - Cannot use controlsend for sending input

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to use the AHK for sending some input when using Cisco AnyConnect.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 
CapsLock::

controlsend,,{enter}, Cisco AnyConnect |  ; this line works
controlsend,,text{enter}, Cisco AnyConnect |  ; this line does not work. I also try to send only text but it does not work either
Send, text{enter} ; this line works
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's possible that it just wont work. ControlSend working is pretty much a hit or miss in my opinion. There might be some other methods that could work for you though. Can you maybe screenshot what the window looks like so I can try to guess something. Also, setting some control in the first parameter could help.

Comment: https://answers.uillinois.edu/images/group180/shared/vpn/47507-login_1.PNG
Here is the screenshot

Comment: Seems pretty promising that it could work. Maybe just choosing the correct control to send to could do the trick. If you don't know what I'm talking about, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95u1dCkgoek) video can probably be of help. So basically just fill in the correct name of the control to the first parameter of your command.